# Bounds for the rank of a symmetric matrix

Tags: symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix.  What can be
said about lower bounds for the rank of $A$ when the
off diagonal elements are small relative to those
on the diagonal?

Question:  In particular, suppose the diagonal elements of $A$ are all
equal to 1 while all the off diagonal elements lie in the open
interval $(-1,1)$. As a function of $n$, how small can 
the rank of $A$ be under these conditions? [Note that in 
the atypical case $n = 2$, $A$ must be nonsingular but that for all 
$n \ge 3$, $\text{rank}(A) \lt n$ is achievable.]

Comment: Since $\operatorname{tr}{A}=n$, it's clear that the rank is at least $1$. Since $A$ is symmetric, $\operatorname{tr}{(A^2)}-(\operatorname{tr}{A})^2 = 2\sum_{j>i} a_{ij}^2+n-n^2 = 2\sum_{j>i} (a_{ij}^2-1)$, which is negative, so has rank at least $2$. I wonder if this pattern continues.

Comment: Notably, we can always achieve rank at most $(2/3)n + 1$ with
$$
\pmatrix{1&-.5&-.5\\
-.5&1&-.5\\
-.5&1&1\\
&&&\ddots\\
&&&&1&-.5&-.5\\
&&&&-.5&1&-.5\\
&&&&-.5&1&1}
$$
(blank entries are zero)

Comment: Also notable: if $A$ and $B$ are matrices of this form with possibly different sizes, then $A \otimes B$ (where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product) is another matrix of this form with 
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A\otimes B) = \operatorname{rank}(A)\operatorname{rank}(B)
$$
consequently, $\operatorname{rank}(A)/n$ can be made arbitrarily small for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: That matrix above should be 
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&-.5&-.5\\ -.5&1&-.5\\ -.5&-.5&1}
$$
and the big matrix is just $I \otimes M$

Comment: We can get the rank down to $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ with matrices of the form $$ \begin{pmatrix} I_k & O^T \\ O & I_m \end{pmatrix}, $$ where $O$ is part of an orthogonal matrix, which have characteristic polynomials of the form $(1-t)^{|k-m|} [(t-2)t]^{\min\{m,k\}} $. In particular, this gives you a $4\times4$ example of rank $2$.

Comment: An example with rank $2$ for $n=5$ is $$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & b & b & a \\ a & 1 & a & b & b \\ b & a & 1 & a & b \\ b & b & a & 1 & a \\ a & b & b & a & 1 \end{pmatrix}, $$ with $a$ and $b$ the roots of $4x^2+2x+1=0$ (roughly $-0.8$ and $0.3$).

Comment: Nice results.  The possibility of a uniform bound is intriguing.  Thanks to both of you for working on it.